# doesn't show action bar items - android

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I don't know what to do with this problem. I changed it a lot but it still don't show sherlock action bar items.
here is my code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater minflater = this.getSupportMenuInflater();
    minflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, (com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu) menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I use Sherlock Activity.
if any one can help me please notice me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater minflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    minflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    return true;
}
```

And make sure you have these imports:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
```

You should try and avoid these: `minflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, (com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu) menu);`

And declare your activity_main.xml like this (pseudo code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuStatusUpdate"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_status"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Status Update">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuPhotoUpload"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_gallery"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Photo">
    </item>    
</menu>
```

You can play with this attribute: `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` and replace the `ifRoom|withText` with `always`

Comment: Thank you for your respond. but when I test it on android 2.1. It force closed.

Comment: @NimaCh: Sorry for the delay. I was away from my workstation after posting the answer. Can you post the crash log in your question? That might help me see if I can find a solution.

Comment: After some tests, I figure out it doesn't crash on android 2.1 device. Sry. But it does not show menu items in < android 2.3

Comment: @NimaCh: Well, honestly, I am not sure why the code I have posted does not work. It works just as advertised in my app. Post your code after the modifications along with your XML too. That might help.

Comment: Please look at my code that I added in this thread. thank you for your support

Comment: @NimaCh: I did not realize you posted it as an Answer. I meant edit your post and add new code. Anyway. Let me take a look.

Comment: @NimaCh: Also, post your Crash Log.

Comment: I can't see the crash log because if I test it in my compiler (eclipse) it doesn't crash but when I test in my device (andorid 2.3) my app crash. do you know a way to test it for android 2.3 in eclipse to give you the crash log

Comment: @NimaCh: If it crashes, there ought to be a error report in your logact. Are you selecting your device in the "Devices" panel in logcat?